# JavaScript loop, create object, but shows zero in length

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript method, where I'm trying to group my data by 'date', which works fine.
But when I look at the length of my object it shows, 'zero'.

Is there a better way to do this? and keep the length of the new variable?

```
groupByDate(snapshot) {
    let list = []
    this.orders.reduce(function (a, c) {
        if(!list[c.date]) {
            list[c.date] = [];
        }
        list[c.date].push(c);
    });

    this.ordersByDate = list
    console.log(list)
}
```

Comment: What is the shape of `orders`?  You shouldn't be using `reduce` like this.  `reduce` returns something.  If you just want to iterate an Array, use `forEach` or a regular `for` loop.

Comment: `list` is an array and it seems you are trying to treat it as an object and attach random properties to it. Those wouldn't be counted as part of the array itself - only numerical keys would.

Comment: that is not how you use reduce. the proper way would be `let list = this.orders.reduce(function (o, c) { o[c.date] = o[c.date] || []; o[c.date].push(c); return o }, {}); console.log(Object.keys(list).length);`

Comment: I couldn't figure your issue with little code provided. you can use keys or entries with your object . 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Are you using your dates as indexes for your array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing properties into an array. You are not setting the indexes of the array. So you should be using an object and not an array. Your use of reduce is also not correct. You are treating it like a forEach loop.

So use an object and use reduce the way it is supposed to be

```
let list = this.orders.reduce(function (o, c) { 
  o[c.date] = o[c.date] || []
  o[c.date].push(c)
  return o
}, {})
console.log(Object.keys(list).length)
```

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize, thought this was the correct way. Thanks for the clarification!!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a dictionary (key, values) for that:

```
list {
    date1: [obj1-1, obj1-2, ...],
    date2: [obj2-1, obj2-2, ...],
    ...
}
```

```js
list = {};
this.orders.forEach(order => {
    if (!list.hasOwnProperty(order.date)) {
        // If it is the first time we meet this date, create an array with th first element
        list[order.date] = [order];
    } else {
        // We have already meet the date, thus the key exists and so do the array. Add element to array
        list[order.date].push(order);
    }
});
```

It seems you have an array and its indexes are the dates. I assume the dates are big numbers (date from 1970 in milliseconds, something like that), which may lead to having a very very big array 99,9% empty. That is why according to me you should use an object and not an array.

Or maybe those are not dates but id's of dates ?